# Can't lower bound be improved on number of light edges in planar graph with minimum degree five?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let an $i$-vertex be a vertex of degree $i$. Let an $i, j-$ edge be an edge joining an $i-$vertex to
a $j-$vertex. Given a plane graph G, let $e_{i,j}$ be the number of $i, j-$edges of $G$.

I found **Borodin** and **Sanders**'s work through the following paper:

- Oleg V. Borodin, Daniel P. Sanders, *On Light Edges and Triangles in Planar Graphs of Minimum Degree Five*, Math. Nach. **170** Issue 1 (1994) pp 19–24, doi:[10.1002/mana.19941700103](https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.19941700103).

**Theorem** Every normal plane map of minimum vertex degree $5$ satisfies

$$\frac{14}{3}e_{5,5}+2e_{5,6}\ge 120.$$
The author says the inequality **cannot be improved**.
Since the following graph is constructed with $e_{5,5}=24$ and $e_{5,6}=4$.

[image]

I am very confused about the reason of "cannot be improved". More clearly the author's graph makes me unconvinced. Because we are not clear about the edges outside this local subgraph $H$. It is still possible that $e_{5,5}>24$ and $e_{5,6}>4$ .
If this happens, it seems that this lower bound  can be improved.

[image]

My point is only if we can construct a graph with $n$ (**arbitrarily large**)vertices with minimum degree $5$, but
$$\frac{14}{3}e_{5,5}+2e_{5,6}= 120.$$
Only then  we can say that the coefficient cannot be improved. Otherwise we might even get
$$ke_{5,5}+le_{5,6}\ge f(n),$$
where $k$ and $l$ are all constant, and $f(n)$ is function about $n$.

After all, there are 5-regular planar graph with $e_{5,5}=\frac{5n}{2}$ by doing limited copy of following graph.
(Regrettably, I haven't thought of the connected graph example with $n$ ($ n>12$) vertices.It will be better.)

[image]
I don’t know if there is a problem with my thinking, I would like to get some guidance.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ask the authors?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. 
Let me think about it first and then I will ask the author.

Comment: My impression is that the authors didn't try to give an infinite family of examples, just a single one. It is obtained by adding a vertex on the outerface and joining it to the 6 half-edges. They do not seem to claim that the coefficients cannot be improved, just that the inequality itself is attained.

Comment: @licheng But you’ve already asked many other people —- here.

Comment: @  Ilya Bogdanov Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem** Every normal plane map of minimum vertex degree 5 satisfies
> $\frac{14}{3} e_{5,5}+2e_{5,6}≥120.$
> The author says the inequality cannot be improved. Since the following graph is constructed with $e_{5,5} =24$ and $e_{5,6} =4$.

I think what they mean by "cannot be improved" is that the constant 120 on the right-hand side cannot be increased.  The graph they show has $\frac{14}{3} e_{5,5}+2e_{5,6}=120$, so we know that 120 is a possible sum.

From your description, maybe you're wondering whether $\frac{14}{3} e_{5,5}+2e_{5,6}$ can be bigger than 120--certainly it can be!  But it won't *always* be bigger than 120, since exactly 120 is possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think your answer helped me understand what the author meant.